# C Read then Write

Tags: c, io

After we do:

```
int readStat = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
```

Why should the following be:

```
int status = write(socket_num, buf, readStat);
```

instead of

```
int status = write(socket_num, buf, sizeof(buf));
```

?
So instead of passing in the size of buf, like the man page instructs, why do we pass in the return value of read?!

Comment: The buffer might be big enough to hold 512 bytes, but if there were only 32 bytes in the file, then `readStat` contains 32, and you don't write anything that wasn't previously read.

Comment: To write what you read and not to write garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read returns the number of bytes actually read, keeping in mind you could have a file 500 bytes long, request to read 500 bytes, but only get 200 returned.  So you should always loop with read till end of file is returned.   This is especially the case with TCP/IP reading, since your pulling from a buffer.

In actuality you probably will always get the amount of bytes you request from a file if there is enough, however this technically is not always true.

But take for example if you had a 32 byte file, and you had a 500 byte buffer.  You would only read in 32 bytes, so the other 500 bytes would be garbage.  Now when you write your new file, its 500 bytes long, instead of 32.